Is there a conflict between Hibernate and Spring Data JPA?
I have 2 entities Book and Author with a many-to-many association between them.
My entities are defined as follows:
Book.java
public class Book  {

@Id
private int id;

private String title;

@ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
@JoinTable(name = "author_book",
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "book_id"),
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "author_id"))
private Set<Author> authors = new HashSet<>();

// constructors, setters, getters, equals and hashCode omitted for brevity
// authors set is not included in equals and hashCode implementation

public void addAuthor(Author author) {
    authors.add(author);
    author.getBooks().add(this);
}

Author.java
public class Author  {

@Id
private int id; 

private String name;

@Column(unique = true)
private String phoneNumber;

@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "authors")
private Set<Book> books = new HashSet<>();

// constructors, setters, getters, equals and hashCode omitted for brevity
// books set is not included in equals and hashCode implementation

 public void addBook(Book book) {
    books.add(book);
    book.getAuthors().add(this);
 }

My problem occurs when I try to insert a book written by an author that already exists!
Demo:
@Bean

ApplicationRunner applicationRunner(BookRepository bookRepository) {
    return args -> {
        Author a1 = new Author("author1", "phone1");
        Author a2 = new Author("author2", "phone2");
        Author a3 = new Author("author3", "phone3");

        Book b1 = new Book();
        b1.setId("id1");
        b1.setName("book1");
        b1.setAuthors(Set.of(a1, a2));

        Book b2 = new Book();
        b2.setId("id2");
        b2.setName("book2");
        b2.setAuthors(Set.of(a1, a3));

        bookRepository.save(b1);
        bookRepository.save(b2);
    };
}

Result:
An exception
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "authors_phone_number_key" Detail: Key (phone_number)=(phone1) already exists.
I tried the same example in pure hibernate as follows:
try (EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager()) {
        em.getTransaction().begin();

        Author a1 = new Author("author1", "phone1");
        Author a2 = new Author("author2", "phone2");
        Author a3 = new Author("author3", "phone3");

        Book b1 = new Book();
        b1.setId("id1");
        b1.setName("book1");
        b1.setAuthors(Set.of(a1, a2));

        Book b2 = new Book();
        b2.setId("id2");
        b2.setName("book2");
        b2.setAuthors(Set.of(a1, a3));

        em.persist(b1);
        em.persist(b2);

        em.getTransaction().commit(); 
    }

and it works like as expected (3 records in authors table, 2 records in books table and 4 records in author_book juncion table!)
Is there anything I'm missing with Spring Data JPA? Does it override a default behaviour in Hibernate that I don't know?
Thank you in advance!

I'm thinking that you need to put bookRepository.save(b1); bookRepository.save(b2); in a transaction or just save the authors first. You're asking too much from the data abstraction layer without understanding the nuances of what you're asking. Keep It Simple Smart. Remove the CascadeType stuff, save the authors yourself first to get it to work. Then make sure you understand your changes.

You shouldn't be setting the collection but rather add the authors. Next to that you aren't re-using the persisted Author instance, which lets hibernate detect it as new. Make sure you implement a proper equals and hashCode implementation which is suitable for JPA.
